# Can you recommend a Python SOAP client that can accept WS-Attachments?

Tags: python, soap

I've read mixed reviews of both [Suds](https://fedorahosted.org/suds/) and [ZSI](http://pywebsvcs.sourceforge.net/) -- two Python SOAP libraries.  However, I'm unclear whether either of them can support WS-Attachments.  I'd prefer to use Suds (appears to be more straightforward), but I'll defer to whichever library suits my needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your requirements I'd have to recommend ZSI. From its documentation,

> It can also be used to build applications using SOAP Messages with Attachments.

Their website is not as pretty as Suds but the package includes promising documentation.

SOAPpy has support for attachments on its TODO list. Suds does not mention the word "attachments" anywhere. If you need attachments and don't want to implement them yourself, then ZSI is your choice.

Comment: Yes, SOAP support in python sucks. Seriously.

Comment: @vezult : are you the same guy who made the soap attachment with suds here : https://fedorahosted.org/suds/attachment/ticket/350/soap_attachments.py ? If it is you I have the following question regarding this post which I formulated here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6601107/how-to-send-a-file-through-soap-in-python

Answer (score 1):

I believe [soaplib](http://trac.optio.webfactional.com/) can handle attachments.  I'm just not sure exactly how compliant it is with WS-Attachments because they don't trumpet it.

Here's a sample client that, their words, allows "multi-part mime payloads":

[helloworld_attach.py](http://trac.optio.webfactional.com/browser/soaplib/trunk/examples/helloworld_attach.py)

Answer (score 0):

In my experience Suds was the only Python package that actually works.  I did not use attachments.

Comment: Did you try ZSI?  If so, what problems did you encounter?