# How to instruct python to wait for a job to run until the variable takes on a certain value

Tags: python, python-3.x, task, scheduled-tasks

I have a certain job in python called "exportjob" (this job basically execute a procedure in external application).
I need that python wait the execution of the code until a variable assume a specific value.
More precisely:
a) the command for exportjob is:

```
exportJob = client.service.SubmitExportJob(USER, CLIENTID, PW, "MB_ExportSet_Portfolio", dt.date(2020, 4, 16), "Exporting Job", True)
```

b) then i get the status of this exportjob by using this command (simply passing him the exportjob variable in the command)

```
status = client.service.GetExportJobStatus(USER, CLIENTID, PW, exportJob)
```

c) the status variable return immediately only one of these values: status= 0 'Export completed succesfully', status<0 'Export failed', status>0 'Export is pending'

I want to tell python (if status>0) TO WAIT UNTIL status=0 (or stopping procedure if status<0)
Someone can help me?

Comment: what about a `while` loop?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a simple `while` loop

```
status = client.service.GetExportJobStatus(USER, CLIENTID, PW, exportJob)
while status > 0:
    status = client.service.GetExportJobStatus(USER, CLIENTID, PW, exportJob)
    sleep(0.1) #not needed but could be used to decrease number of iterations (pauses program for 0.1 seconds)
#new status is either =0 or <0 so you can execute the rest of your program
```

Comment: Thank you very much, now it work properly. Can i ask you another question if possible? Soon after submitting the job and successfully exported status, i get the file with another job like this: dataWrk = client.service.GetExportJob(USER, CLIENTID, PW, exportJob). I need to link the dataWrk to a zip object file and then extract it. I'm working under soap SUDS JURKO

Comment: No problem. But since I have never worked with SOAP in python I'm afraid I can't be of any help. If you are asking about sending a zip object you could check out [How to send a file through Soap in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6601107/how-to-send-a-file-through-soap-in-python).